# SAS Are there any function for take sample by variables?

Tags: sas

I need take a sample by variables of diferents size in a sas data set.

For example given this sas data set:

```
 V1    V2    V3
 0.9   3.3   32
 1.2   4.2   31
 0.4   1.8   45
   7   6.3   67
  .8   1.5   82
 5.9   4.3   62
```

I have take a simple random sample by variables (V1--V3). In V1 the size is 2, in V2 the size is 4 and in V3 the is 5.

Finally I want have three data sets with samples, that is:

```
V1_sample
0.2
0.4

V2_sample
3.3
1.5
4.2
6.3

V3_sample
82
62
45
31
31
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I think you aren't sufficiently explaining what you're trying to do.  What are you wanting as an output?

Comment: I want three data sets with samples of V1, V2 and V3.

Comment: Show those in the question - what would one example set of those datasets look like?  How are you sampling?

Comment: Using simple random sample for each variable, where size change by variable. That is, for variable V1 take a simple random sample with size 2.

Comment: You need to put, *in the question*, an example of what the three datasets need to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely unnecessary to make separate datasets to perform this.

Using Broseph's example data:

```
data data;
input v1 v2 v3;
cards;
0.9 3.3 32
1.2 4.2 31
0.4 1.8 45
7 6.3 67
.8 1.5 82
5.9 4.3 62
;
run;

proc surveyselect data=data method=urs n=2 out=v1_sample(keep=v1);
run;
proc surveyselect data=data method=urs n=3 out=v2_sample(keep=v2);
run;
proc surveyselect data=data method=urs n=5 out=v3_sample(keep=v3);
run;
```

However a perhaps more SAS-sy method of doing this would be to keep everything in a single dataset.

```
data have;
  set data;
  array v[3];
  do _i = 1 to dim(v);
    var = vname(v[_i]);
    val = v[_i];
    output;
  end;
run;

data sample_counts;
  input var $ _NSIZE_;
  datalines;
v1 2
v2 3
v3 5
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by var;
run;

proc surveyselect data=have out=want n=sample_counts method=urs outhits;
strata var;
run;
```

Then you do whatever analysis BY those variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could just subset your dataset and then run proc surveyselect to grab a SRS of whatever size you wish one dataset at a time.  The following code will output 3 separate data sets which are simple random samples of size n of each of the v1,v2, v3 columns.  I don't know if you can do this all in one procedure, in theory you should be able to create a program that will do it, having differing sample sizes will make it a bit messy. I would use R if I wanted to create a function to do this in a more automated fashion, I find these types of problems easier to handle in R, but that's me.

```
data data;
input v1 v2 v3;
cards;
0.9 3.3 32
1.2 4.2 31
0.4 1.8 45
7 6.3 67
.8 1.5 82
5.9 4.3 62
;
run;

data v1;
set work.data; 
keep v1;
run;

data v2;
set work.data;
keep v2;
run;

data v3;
set work.data;
keep v3;
run;

proc surveyselect data=work.v1 method=srs n=2 out=v1sample;
run;
proc surveyselect data=work.v2 method=srs n=4 out=v2sample;
run;
proc surveyselect data=work.v3 method=srs n=5 out=v3sample;
run;
```

Comment: Based on the example given for v3_sample (in which 31 appears twice), it looks like you'd want to use method = urs instead of srs,

Comment: If I have some missing values in variables, how can I procede with sampling without these missing values?

Comment: [See here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyselect_sect014.htm), looks like there are some different ways in which this procedure can handle missing data depending on which suits your problem best.